# If we let $\delta < 1$, then why do we set $\delta$ to be the minimum of $1$ and $\frac{\epsilon}{5}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

### Using $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition, show that $\lim_{x \to 2} x^{2} = 4$.

The **proof** according to [Example 7: Evaluating a limit using the definition](http://Example%207:%20Evaluating%20a%20limit%20using%20the%20definition)

$|x^{2}-4|<\epsilon \implies |x-2|<\frac{\epsilon}{|x+2|}$

Let $\delta < 1$, then $|x-2|<1$

$-1<x-2<1$

$1<x<3$

$3<x+2<5$

$\frac{1}{5}<\frac{1}{|x+2|}<\frac{1}{3}$

$\frac{\epsilon}{5}<\frac{\epsilon}{|x+2|}<\frac{\epsilon}{3}$

Let $\delta \leq \frac{\epsilon}{5}$, then $|x-2| < \frac{\epsilon}{5}$

$|x^{2}-4| < |x+2|\frac{\epsilon}{5}$

As long as $\delta < 1$, we get:

$|x^{2}-4| < |x+2|\frac{\epsilon}{5}< |x+2|\frac{\epsilon}{|x+2|} $

$|x^{2}-4| < \epsilon$

However, we could have let $\delta \leq 1$, which will make the proof still true. Consider the following two cases:

**Case I:** $\delta < 1$

$\delta < 1 \implies |x-2|< \delta < 1 \implies |x-2|<1$.

**Case II:** $\delta \leq 1$

$\delta \leq 1 \implies |x-2|< \delta \leq 1 \implies |x-2|<1$ for either $\delta < 1$ and $\delta = 1$

Thus, $\delta \leq \frac{\epsilon}{5} \leq 1 $

Furthermore, the source states:

> For the final fix, we set $\delta$ to be the minimum of $1$ and $\frac{\epsilon}{5}$. This way all caculations above work.

This would mean $\delta \leq min(1, \frac{\epsilon}{5})$ since, by definition, a smaller $\delta$ such as $0<|x-a|<\delta^{'}<\delta$ will imply that $|f(x)-L| < \epsilon$ and that $1$ or $\frac{\epsilon}{5}$ will satisfy the implication depending on $\epsilon$. Therefore, we can have $\delta \leq 1$

### Question

In summary, is it better to start off with $\delta \leq 1$ over $\delta < 1$, right?

Comment: Uhh, you're agreeing with the statement - it says that if $\delta$ is not less than 1, it wont work. Which means it only works if $\delta \leq 1$ - which is what you have demonstrated. To counter the statement assume $\delta  > 1$

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan You're right! This is silly....

Comment: I've modified my post so it makes sense. Thank you for pointing out the error.

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan  "it says that if $\delta$ is not less than 1, it wont' work." Well, if $\delta = 1$, then is not less than 1, but still works...

Comment: Minor nuance: it is very common in $\delta, \epsilon$ proofs to use the $\min$ function.  However, the min function is normally used  on a *less than or equal to* basis, rather than a *less than basis*.  So, when (for example) it is specified that $\delta = \min[(\epsilon/5), 1]$ this is insufficient for guaranteeing that $\delta < 1.$  Normally, if I want to ensure something like $\delta < (\epsilon/5)$ and $\delta < 1$, I will specify $\delta = \min[(\epsilon/10), (1/2)].$  Unclear to me whether a teacher will accept a specification that starts $\delta < \cdots$ rather than $\delta = \cdots$